# Post request returns empty body response (200-none) python

Tags: json, flask, python-requests

Sending post response to a machine learning API returns empty body ,
the code for the request is simple :

```
import json
import requests
for row in new_f.itertuples():
            features = [{
                       'CRIM' : str(row.CRIM), 
                       'ZN' : str(row.ZN), 
                       'INDUS' : str(row.INDUS), 
                       'CHAS' : str(row.CHAS), 
                       'NOX' : str(row.NOX), 
                       'RM' : str(row.RM), 
                       'AGE' : str(row.AGE), 
                       'DIS' : str(row.DIS), 
                       'RAD' : str(row.RAD), 
                       'TAX' : str(row.TAX), 
                       'PTRATIO' : str(row.PTRATIO), 
                       'B' : str(row.B), 
                       'LSTAT' : str(row.LSTAT)
                       }]
            postre = json.dumps(features)
            print(postre)
            response  = requests.post(url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict' , data= postre )
            print(response.json())
```

the output of print(postre) is :

```
[{"CRIM": "0.00632", "ZN": "18.0", "INDUS": "2.31", "CHAS": "0", "NOX": "0.538", "RM": "6.575", "AGE": "65.2", "DIS": "4.09", "RAD": "1", "TAX": "296.0", "PTRATIO": "15.3", "B": "396.9", "LSTAT": "4.98"}]
```

when printing response.json an error rises :

**line 34, in predict\n    query_ =pd.get_dummies(pd.DataFrame(json_)).....ValueError: No objects to concatenate\n'}**

Here is Post api methode snippet :

```
if flask.request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            json_ =request.json
            print(json_)
            query_ =pd.get_dummies(pd.DataFrame(json_))
            query = query_.reindex(columns = model_columns, fill_value = 0)
            prediction = list(classifier.predict(query))

            return jsonify({
                "prediction":str(prediction)
            })
        except:
            return jsonify({
                "trace": traceback.format_exc()
            })
```

Post man request application returns the desired results :

```
{
    "prediction": "[42.267999999999994]"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can send the list in requests without serializing. And, if you send it as `json`, it will change the `Content-Type` in the header to `application/json`.  So, use:

```
response = requests.post(url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict', json=features)
```

Then, so you can see what the response is, try:

```
print(request.get_json())
print(request.json)
```

If you use:

```
get_json(force=True), it will try to parse it as JSON even if you send with wrong mimetype.
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you import request from Flask?

write `json_ = flask.request.json`

instead of `json_ = request.json`

Comment: I did ! still no luck